# Convert datetime to local time from Django Query to Openpyxl

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone, openpyxl

Django converts the date time (I use timezone.now() to store in database) to local time in templates fine. What I need help on is when it is written to a cell in openpyxl.

Right now, I simply assign the attribute of the query to the cell.

```
query = SomeModel.objects.latest()
date_recorded = query.date_recorded
```

In templates, date_recorded is already converted to local time. No problem there.

```
ws.cell(row=rows, column=cols).value = date_recorded
```

The above code results to UTC. Please help me convert it to local time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using ***pytz*** python package.

```
import pytz
# UTC to IST
time_zone = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata') # set timezone here
date_recorded = time_zone.localize(query.date_recorded)
```